# Is there a way to use Metatrader4 C++ version dll with C# to connect to live server

Tags: c#, c++, metatrader4

My application is based on asp.net mvc , c# and my client want to connect this application with MT4 server.There is server api  https://support.metaquotes.net/ru/docs/mt4/api/server_api
which is in c++.This api help to login at MT4.My application is in Asp.net mvc c# and i want to call these c++ methods in c#.
Is it possible to work with c#.
tAHNKS

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? What do you want to know that would not be satisfied by clicking through the first five or ten links of the obvious Google search on the topic?

Comment: Do you have manager/administrator access to server?

Comment: No we don't have any access.But this site have php version of code also through which we can communicate to live server.providing ip address and other credential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server API is tend to be used to write server plugins, which will be loaded into server memory at runtime. You can use .NET code there, however it's not the best idea.

There is Manager API, I think, it's functionality is sufficient for web application. However officially it has only C++ API. But you can use my wrapper to access it from ASP.NET: https://github.com/Uriil/MetaTrader4.Manager.Wrapper

But both options requires manager credentials

Comment: Thanks Urill, So using your wrapper should i create new account on MT4 server.So my all concern is to connect with MT4 with manager credential and then add new user to MT4.

Comment: Yep, it won't be a problem

Comment: Can you expose any method or Interface for User Registration which i invoke in c# and pass value to c++ method.Please any link or guide line.

Comment: @MohsinAli method UserRecordNew

Comment: ClrWrapper took login as integer but i have string value provided by my client. Here is your example Login = 123456.What should i do now.Sorry

Comment: Internally login is integer, and if you have string, it means your client have some custom authentication and you need to discuss it with him

Comment: Sure i'm going to discuss with him. Thanks

Comment: I get new credentials and added a user using UserRecordNew and it returned me 1.so my client told me it should be 4,5 digits like 1234.In my case it returned 1 so what it does means.

Comment: Result is status of operation. Newly created login will be assigned to Login  property of passed UserRecord object. Mandatory parameters: Name, Group, Password, InvestorPassword, Leverage

Comment: 3 2016.10.44 15:44:07.150 185.97.161.40:445 '1': new user record (Invalid parameters). Log file helped me.Thanks once again

Comment: Check that you provided existing group name, and passwords at least 7 characters and contain lowercase, uppercase and number

Comment: Dear Uriil i'm facing Failed to instantiate manager instance exception.

Comment: I need more details, like sample code, which through exception

Comment: I created my MVC4 project in vs2013 and installed it via Nuget Package Manager after that inside my home controller i instantiate using (var metatrader = new ClrWrapper(new ConnectionParameters
            {
                Login = 1,
                Password = "passwordValue",
                Server = "111.11.111.33:111"
            }))
            {
                IList<UserRecord> users = metatrader.UsersRequest();
            }  instantiate manager instance exception

Comment: Can you try same steps in console application?

Comment: It is working perfectly in console but in mvc it throws exception.

Comment: Constructor has second parameter, path to api dll, please provide it

Comment: Additional information: Failed to instantiate manager instance. var path = Server.MapPath("~/bin")+@"\bin\P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper.dll";
            using (var metatrader = new ClrWrapper(new ConnectionParameters
            {
                Login = 1,
                Password = "password",
                Server = "111.11.111.11:111"
            },path ))
            {
                IList<UserRecord> users = metatrader.UsersRequest();
            }

Comment: An exception of type 'P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.Contracts.MetaTraderException' occurred in P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Failed to instantiate manager instance

Comment: Any suggestions Uriil

Comment: Try to provide path explicitly, and me broken code once again

Comment: It is working on implicit path also e.g  Server.MapPath.

Comment: You don't need to broke your code again.Its perfectly working.I come with little typo mistake.

Comment: When i execute it on my client machine it throws now Could not load file or assembly 'P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.Should i need it add it in web.config?

Comment: how do you host it?

Comment: Its not about hosting, actually i gave the running solution project to my client and he try to run on his side and he told me about Exceptoin Could not load file or assembly 'P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper.DLL'.

Comment: Install visual c++ redistributable 2015 x86

Comment: got it as it work perfect as i already have vs2015 , for hosting what should i consider on hosting server. do i need visual c++ redistributable 2015 x86 on hosting server.

Comment: great, any guide or explicit steps about adding these package to my solution.Thanks

Comment: U have to install it from Microsoft web site

Comment: i already have these on my machine but for hosting server do i need to copy these from Microsoft web site and add it to my solution.Its little bit confusing for me that's why i asked you.Any how thanks i'm googling now

Comment: U need to install them on host server, not copy

Comment: My client has Hostgator hosting.Is there a ways of installing binaries or packages directly on any hosting site.

Comment: I guess it depends on provider and you have to talk with your server administrator. I always using dedicated server, so it's not an issue in my case

Comment: Uriil i got reply You wont be able to us c++ on a shared windows plan.You will have to get a dedicated server to get that installed.So Is there any other way?

Comment: You will have to investigate it on your own. However I would consider switching to dedicated server, since prices for them are low

Comment: Uriil i want to get user history on MT4 by its MT4 id.Is there any method which return me a collection.i am looking for fields type,balance,equity.

Comment: The most close one is:DailyReportsRequest

Comment: Thanks Uriil i have to explore this method

Comment: One more thing Uriil i need a method which updates the specific user information.

Comment: Uriil UserRecordUpdate is not wroking. i am trying to update the balance field.When i checked the fetched data its Id field is empty but login and other fields values are still there.Record not updated.Is UserRecordUpdate  method required Id values for updating.

Comment: To change balance, u need to use TradeTransaction. But I suggest u to read documentation for mtmanapi on support.metaquotes.com

Comment: TradeTransaction accepts TradeTransInfo instance and it has no field with balance.Actually i need a method which update the UserRecord class field Balance.UserRecordUpdate  take UserRecord instance but it doesn't update the Balance field.

Comment: U realy need to go through documentation

Comment: Uriil Any exact link to document.I really appreciate.

Comment: https://support.metaquotes.net/en/docs/mt4/api/manager_api/manager_api_dev

Comment: Uriil TradeTransInfo accepts two parameters info.type =  TT_BR_BALANCE;
info.cmd    =OP_BALANCE; I need guide on TT_BR_BALANCE and OP_BALANCE values.I got this in docs.this example is in c++

Comment: Complete example //Deposit / Withdraw (assumes login: the account of the user, amount how much to deposit)
TradeTransInfo info={0};

info.type   =TT_BR_BALANCE;
info.cmd    =OP_BALANCE;
info.orderby=login;   
info.price=amount;   //negative for withdrawal
strcpy_s(info.comment, "No comment");
int res=ExtManager->TradeTransaction(&info);
if (res != RET_OK){
MessageBox("Could not deposit");

Comment: i tried with only price field.here is my code.var info = new TradeTransInfo();
                    info.OrderBy = 123456; //Login value
                    //info.Cmd = OP_BALANCE;
                    info.Price = -model.LiveUserWithdrawFund.Amount;
                  var i=  metatrader.TradeTransaction(info);

Comment: I want to update Balance values as user want to withdraw his money.I also read the doc but i'm failed to understand. https://support.metaquotes.net/en/forum/3349

Comment: i got the values. var info = new TradeTransInfo();
                    info.OrderBy = 123456;
                    info.Cmd = TradeCommand.Balance;
                    info.Price =- model.LiveUserWithdrawFund.Amount;
                  var i=  metatrader.TradeTransaction(info);

Comment: U missing type property

Comment: i did info.Type = TradeTransactionType.BrBalance;

Comment: "Repository unavailable due to DMCA takedown." @Uriil